# How to verify a list of similar locators by single assertion in Typescript Playwright

Tags: javascript, typescript, automation, e2e-testing, playwright

I have an Array of Locators and I need to run an assertion to verify if it contains certain text. I am aware that this can be done in a loop however it seems like a tedious approach and I would like to improve it.

Tedius approach:

```
  let textIsPresent : boolean = false;

  for (let entry of arrayOfLocators) {
    if(arrayOfLocators[entry].innerText().toContain("myText")){
       textIsPresent = true;
       break;
    }
  }

  expect(textIsPresent).toBe(true)
```

Is there a better way to do this? For example, using anonymous functions or even built in smart functions? I'm not too strong with Javascript/Typescript and would appreciate any support. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// for exact string match
await expect(locator).toHaveText(['Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3']);
    
//for partial substring match     
await expect(locator).toContainText(['1', '2', '3']);
```

**Note** :If you pass an array as an expected value, the expectations are:

- Locator resolves to a list of elements.
- The number of elements equals the number of expected values in the array.
- Elements from the list have text matching expected array values, one by one, in order.

For example, consider the following list:

```
<ul>
  <li>Text 1</li>
  <li>Text 2</li>
  <li>Text 3</li>
</ul>
```

Let's see how we can use the assertion:

```
// ✓ Has the right items in the right order
await expect(page.locator('ul > li')).toHaveText(['Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3']);

// ✖ Wrong order
await expect(page.locator('ul > li')).toHaveText(['Text 3', 'Text 2', 'Text 1']);

// ✖ Last item does not match
await expect(page.locator('ul > li')).toHaveText(['Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text']);

// ✖ Locator points to the outer list element, not to the list items
await expect(page.locator('ul')).toHaveText(['Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3']);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is still doesn't adresses the question been asked.
The author looks for the way to assert that every list item contains certain substring.
ex. 
const list = ['for user', 'for admin', 'for aliens']
const keyword = 'for'

And the simple answer is
list.foreach(item => expect(item).toContain(keyword))

But playwright gives us more safe way to make it flakiness-proof with expect.poll() and expect().toPass() methods

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77612045/9957089

Comment: Thanks for the last update! toContainText is almost perfect, but it doesn't cover situation, when you don't know the exact number of results, ex. results of search fields, filtering fields etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a flakiness-safe approach that is aligned with playwright web first assertions approach and which suits the lists with unknown length

```
const keyword = 'for'

await expect(async () => {
  const items = await page.locator('div.listItems');
  items.forEach(item => {
    expect(item).toContain(keyword);
  });
}
).toPass({ timeout: 5000 });
```

With this approach the function within *await expect(async () =>* block will be polled and retried for up to 5 seconds untill it pass or or fail by timeout.